# What does MMID refer to in this screenshot?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-exchanges, level-2-quotes

When looking at a level 2 table, we'll usually see:
[image]

So we see 2 tables, one for bids and one for asks. For each, we see 3 columns. What I don't understand is the MMID column.

I understand that it stands for Market Maker ID. But as far as I know, a market maker is a stock exchange participant. And from these 4 letter identifiers it seems that they stand for different stock exchanges, not specific stock exchange participants.

Is there some inter-stock-exchange activity? Are there securities passing from one stock exchange to another?

Would be great if someone can elaborate.

Comment: What's the source for your screenshot?

Comment: Some YouTube video, why?

Comment: @YoavKlein Helps determine the screenshot's credibility. Something from a low-quality website/random YouTuber _could_ just have been thrown together with no real meaning.

Comment: Umm.. these are screenshots, which I've seen very similar in other videos with same values, so...

Comment: @YoavKlein did you ask the YouTuber?  Seems like a good place to start.

Comment: Guys, please, if you have an answer - answer. If not, don't.

Comment: @YoavKlein comments are for requesting clarification, which is exactly what the commenters are doing.

Answer (score 1):

MMID is the "Market Maker Identifier", a 4-letter ID that identifies individual market makers and is assigned by FINRA (Financial Industry Regulatory Authority Inc.)

Here in this L2 table, you see the NBBO (National Best Bid and Offer) prices. Most symbols are traded at multiple exchanges, and yes you are correct that the prices are quoted by market makers at different exchanges. Just because you see the prices at different exchanges does not necessarily mean **you** can trade at these prices though.